# Firefox ignores height and min-height on element (works in Safari and Chrome)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm having some issues making things appear properly in Firefox (max). Specifically with setting the height of some divs. It works fine in both Safari and Chrome, but Firefox seems to ignore both `min-height` and `height` in this case. The relevant markup looks like this (I use Bootstrap and HAML):

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-1
    .col-md-2
      [some content]
    .col-md-8
      / This is where I want to make a w: 100% and h: 150px gray box
      .gray.pull-right.min-height-150.full-width

        %h3.margin-left-20
          = @user.name

        %p.full-width.margin-left-20
          [some text]
    .col-md-1
```

The code above works fine in Safari and Chrome, it creates a gray box 150px heigh, but in Firefox it is 108px heigh, and it seems to base it's height on the content of the container.

My `min-height-150` class is very simple, it looks like this:

```
.min-height-150 {
  min-height: 150px !important;
}
```

I have tried to use `height` as well, but I then get the same result.

So, any ideas on what can be causing this?

Would also appreciate any feedback regarding my Boostrap markup, haven't used it much before.

Comment: try adding display:block; in your min-height-150 class and see if that works

Comment: What sort of element is `.min-height-150`? Is it a span, a div, or some other type? It's pretty peculiar that setting display: block would make it work on Firefox where it wasn't necessary on the other two.

Comment: @BoltClock it's a div class